# Laravel change get parameter in url string and return

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using get parameters for search filters, and need to be able to change a value of the query string variable and return the modified url (as a string variable, nothing fancy, no redirect or anything). This is what I have so far and what is happening:

```
public function index(Request $request){

    echo $request->fullUrl();
    // outputs https://test.com/search?type=somestring

    $request->merge(['type' => 'anotherstring']);

    echo $request->fullUrl();
    // still outputs https://test.com/search?type=somestring

    // is there a way to change a parameter value in the url and
    // return the modified url string?

}
```

I figure if worse comes to worse, I'll just parse the string manually, but it feels like there's a "laravel way" to go about this that I happen to be missing?

Comment: To change the URL in the browser address bar you either need to redirect or use JavaScript. There's no way around it.

Comment: I don't want to change the url in the address bar, I simply want to modify the url string and save it as a variable

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `fullUrlWithQuery` instead.

```
echo $request->fullUrlWithQuery(['type' => 'anotherstring']);
```

Comment: If you use URL::forceScheme('https'), in your app service provider, this will not generate https urls, you will have to use url()->full()

Answer (score 0):

Worse case you can do:

```
 echo url()->current().(!empty($request->all())?"?":"").http_build_query($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to keep some previous parameter and replace/add others:

```
$request->fullUrlWithQuery(array_merge($request->all(),['overwritten'=>'changed_value','added'=>'new_value']));
```

it replaces the query with a merge of previous parameters, adding and overwriting with the new parameters